# Remove text from string until it reaches a certain character

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm having a issue trying to figure out this. I need to "fix" some links, here is an example:

1. www.site.com/link/index.php?REMOVETHISHERE
2. www.site.com/index.php?REMOVETHISHERE

So basically I want to remove everything till it reaches the ? character. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you guarantee only one '?' in your string?

Comment: Yeah. Parapura posted already what I wanted, thank you.

Comment: @DanielMallott: if it's a valid url, it *has* only one `?` ...

Comment: @JoshMikel: So give Parapura the points ...

Comment: @Fischermaen: That is true, and I was forgetting about the LastIndexOf method.

Comment: @Fischermaen I need to wait 8 minutes till I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
 string s = @"www.site.com/link/index.php?REMOVETHISHERE";
 s = s.Remove( s.LastIndexOf('?') );
 //Now s will be simply "www.site.com/link/index.php"
```

should do it

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted. I'm such an idiot. I will accept it in 9 minutes.

Comment: nitpicking, but `IndexOf` would probably be preferable to `LastIndexOf`

Comment: @minnow why ???  If the string had more than one `?` OP probably wants the last one

Comment: I think it's better to use the System.Uri type which encapsulates this and removes the ambiguity of explicit string operations. It has methods defined for extracting partial URL information, e.g. everything apart from the query string, which seems to be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 4):

Although a properly crafted string operation will work, the more general way to extract partial URI information is to use the [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) type which has methods which encapsulate these operations, e.g.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.site.com/link/index.php?REMOVETHISHERE");
var part = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
```

This will convey the intent of your code more clearly and you'll be re-using a current implementation which is known to work.

The `System.Uri` constructor will throw an exception if the string does not represent a valid URI, but you will anyway probably want to invoke some other behavior in your program if an invalid URI has been encountered. To detect an invalid URI you can either catch the exception or use one of the [`TryCreate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx) overloads.

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.split`.

```
string URL = "www.site.com/link/index.php?REMOVETHISHERE"
var parts = URL.Split('?');
```

Then `parts[0]` will contain "www.site.com/link/index.php" and `parts[1]` will contain "REMOVETHISHERE". You can then use which ever part you want.

You should add checks to make sure that there are two parts before trying to access the 2nd element of the array. You could (for example) check that the string contains "?" before trying to call `Split`.

Answer (score 1):

To remove last "?" and everything after it:

```
    string input = @"www.site.com/link/index.php?REMOVETHISHERE";
    input = input.Remove(input.LastIndexOf('?'));

    OR

    string input = @"www.site.com/link/index.php?REMOVETHISHERE";
    input = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf('?'));
```

Now the output will be:

```
www.site.com/link/index.php
```