# Regex + Remove all text before match

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to figure out a way to remove all text in a string before match in Regex. I'm coding this in C#.

For example, if the string is "hello, test matching", and the pattern is "test", I would like the final  result to be "test matching" (ie remove everything before test).

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

EDIT:  I probably should have been a bit more specific in my example after reading your responses (and thanks for them).  I like the lookahead method, but I oversimplified my example.  To make things more difficult, usually the strings look like:

"hello, test matching test everythingAfter"

So if I use the pattern "test", it will catch the first one.  What my goal is, is to replace all text after the second match. Ie: result in "test everythingAfter"....  Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with C# to write the code. However, don't use a RegEx, use basic string methods. *search* to find the occurrence, than use *substring* capture *everything after*.

Comment: For the patterns you are trying to remove, are they always strings or are they sometimes actual regular expressions? If the former, use `IndexOf` and `Substring` and avoid performance penalties that you don't need.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Remove text from string until it reaches a certain character](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8371922/299327)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated, using matchcollection

```
string test = "hello, test matching";

string regexStrTest;
regexStrTest = @"test\s\w+";       
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(test, regexStrTest);
//gets the second matched value
string value = m1[1].Value;
```

Comment: That's a *lookbehind*, not a lookahead, and it's not doing anything useful.  If `"test\s"` has just consumed `test` followed by a space, then of course a lookbehind for `"test "` is going to succeed.  Also, the `Singleline` option has no effect because the `.` metacharacter isn't used in the regex.

Comment: Well, the non-functional extra code is gone, but this still returns the *second* occurrence of `test` and *one word* following it.  In a comment to another answer, the OP said it's really the *last* occurrence he wants (you should update the question again, @keynes), and the match should include everything after that, not just one word.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match a string but not capture it:

```
(?=test)
```

So you want to capture the stuff before the last occurrence of test:

```
^.*(?=test)
```

If you want to make it so that it is the first occurrence of test, use lazy matching:

```
^.*?(?=test)
```

Comment: Thx for the response - made an edit to the problem above... I like that lookahead approach though. Can I select the 2nd match and then do look ahead?

Comment: how would you capture everything after the occurrence?

Answer (score 5):

For a simple solution, just replace "*start-of-line* *anything* test" with "test":

```
newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, "^.*test", "test");
```

Since `*` is greedy, this will replace as much as possible, i.e. `a test b test c` will become `test c`. To replace as little as possible, use `*?` instead of `*`.

If you want to avoid duplicating the search word, you can use a [Zero-width positive lookahead assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion):

```
newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, "^.*(?=test)", "");
```

Comment: This will remove everything before the *last* match of `test`. It may not matter in many cases, but it may be confusing too.

Comment: Actually, as I read down the responses now, this is exactly what I need to do (see my edit above). I need it to match to the last result, and the replace everything before it.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @keynesiancross: If that's the case, you should accept this answer or the one from Heinzi, *not* Paul's.  Nothing personal, Paul, but that one only works by accident.

Comment: Hardly only works by accident as the question didn't state that he only wanted the last match. Only after I answered it did he comment this.