# Remove all text in string until it reaches multiple characters match

Tags: c#

I want to remove everything after this is matches:

```
/**
```

My string is:

> /r/_ylt=A0oG7lyFHLZQjSEAWltXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTE0NGYxbHRnBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDOQRjb2xvA2FjMgR2dGlkA1ZJUDA0OV83Nw--/SIG=11pqblim6/EXP=1354140933/**http%3a//www.hellomagazine.com/royalty/" target="_blank" data-bk="5254.1" dirtyhref="/r/_ylt=A0oG7lyFHLZQjSEAWltXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTE0NGYxbHRnBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDOQRjb2xvA2FjMgR2dGlkA1ZJUDA0OV83Nw--/SIG=11pqblim6/EXP=1354140933/**http%3a//www.hellomagazine.com/royalty/

I want to remove everything before `/**`

I can make it match by 1 character, but how can i do it for multiple characters?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) ?

Comment: I have tried: baseUrlsen = baseUrlsen.Substring(baseUrlsen.IndexOf('/') + 1);

Comment: And have you looked at the [documentation of `IndexOf` to see if there is an overload that takes a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904283%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), rather than `char`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Remove text from string until it reaches a certain character](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8371922/299327)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `Substring` with `IndexOf` works:

```
string output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(@"/**") + @"/**".Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried? How do you match on one character, and why can't you change that to multiple characters? String manipulation is documented perfectly.

You need something like this:

```
string input = "your string/**result";
string separator = "/**";
int startPos = input.IndexOf(separator);

if (startPos == -1)
{
    return input;
}

return input.Substring(startPos + separator.Length);
```

Omit the `+ separator.Length` if you do want to return the separator too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputstr = "your input string";
int index = inputstr.IndexOf(@"/**");
if (index > 0)
{
  var result = inputstr.Substring(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your string is called `myString`

```
myString = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("/**") + 1)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test="/r/_ylt=A0oG7lyFHLZQjSEAWltXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTE0NGYxbHRnBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDOQRjb2xvA2FjMgR2dGlkA1ZJUDA0OV83Nw--/SIG=11pqblim6/EXP=1354140933/**http%3a//www.hellomagazine.com/royalty/\" target=\"_blank\" data-bk=\"5254.1\" dirtyhref=\"/r/_ylt=A0oG7lyFHLZQjSEAWltXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTE0NGYxbHRnBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDOQRjb2xvA2FjMgR2dGlkA1ZJUDA0OV83Nw--/SIG=11pqblim6/EXP=1354140933/**http%3a//www.hellomagazine.com/royalty/";
        var value=test.Split(new string[]{"/**"},StringSplitOptions.None);
        //continue working with value[0], value[0] etc
    }
}
```